# put intermediary outputs in appendix

Tags: r-markdown

I'm doing an analysis in R, and for the assignment I need to put intermediary products (e.g. the coefficients table, or the estimated model) in the appendix. I know I can save the dataframes and output them as tables later, but is there a way to say "output this table, but in a section named/labeled "appendix"? That way I can keep the entirety of the analysis together.